# Not able to clear text fields using reset method in flutter form

Tags: forms, flutter, textfield, flutter-widget, flutter-form-builder

I am designing a form in flutter which is taking input for two text fields using TextField widgets, one time field using DateTimeField and one day picker using WeekDay selector widget. I have used the reset method to reset the form but this is only resetting the BasicTimeField widget and is unable to reset all other fields.

```
class MyCustomForm extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyCustomForm({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyCustomForm> createState() => _MyCustomFormState();
}

class _MyCustomFormState extends State<MyCustomForm> {
  final formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var ht = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
    var wd = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    return Form(
      key: formKey,
      child: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: <Widget>[
          SizedBox(
            height: ht / 20,
          ),
          Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: wd / 40, vertical: 1),
            child: Text(
              "Subject",
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: ht / 30, fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),
            ),
          ),
          Padding(
            padding:
                EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: wd / 40, vertical: ht / 60),
            child: TextField(
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                border: OutlineInputBorder(), // UnderlineInputBorder(),
                hintText: 'Type Subject name here',
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: wd / 40, vertical: 1),
            child: Text(
              "Class Link",
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: ht / 30, fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),
            ),
          ),
          Padding(
            padding:
                EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: wd / 40, vertical: ht / 60),
            child: const TextField(
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                border: OutlineInputBorder(), // UnderlineInputBorder(),
                hintText: 'Paste class link here',
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Center(
              child: Text(
            "Timing",
            style: TextStyle(fontSize: ht / 30, fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),
          )),
          Row(mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center, children: [
            BasicTimeField(),
            SizedBox(
              width: wd / 9,
              child: Center(
                child: Text(
                  "to",
                  style:
                      TextStyle(fontSize: ht / 40, fontWeight: FontWeight.w400),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            BasicTimeField()
          ]),
          SizedBox(
            height: ht / 40,
          ),
          Center(
              child: Text(
            "Select days of week",
            style: TextStyle(fontSize: ht / 30, fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),
          )),
          DayPicker(),
          SizedBox(
            height: ht / 20,
          ),
          Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              ElevatedButton(
                child: Text('Add'),
                onPressed: () => formKey.currentState?.save(),
              ),
              const SizedBox(
                width: 50,
              ),
              ElevatedButton(
                child: Text('Reset'),
                onPressed: () => formKey.currentState?.reset(),
              ),
            ],
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

reset in your form is not working because you are using a textfield which will not reset when using

```
formKey.currentState?.reset()
```

> Try changing the Textform to TextFormField

Now, it will work.

**Full Updated Code(From your code)**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class MyCustomForm extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyCustomForm({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyCustomForm> createState() => _MyCustomFormState();
}

class _MyCustomFormState extends State<MyCustomForm> {
  final formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var ht = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
    var wd = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    return Scaffold(
      body: Form(
        key: formKey,
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: <Widget>[
            SizedBox(
              height: ht / 20,
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: wd / 40, vertical: 1),
              child: Text(
                "Subject",
                style:
                    TextStyle(fontSize: ht / 30, fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),
              ),
            ),
            Padding(
              padding:
                  EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: wd / 40, vertical: ht / 60),
              child: TextFormField(
                decoration: const InputDecoration(
                  border: OutlineInputBorder(), // UnderlineInputBorder(),
                  hintText: 'Type Subject name here',
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: wd / 40, vertical: 1),
              child: Text(
                "Class Link",
                style:
                    TextStyle(fontSize: ht / 30, fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),
              ),
            ),
            Padding(
              padding:
                  EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: wd / 40, vertical: ht / 60),
              child: TextFormField(
                decoration: const InputDecoration(
                  border: OutlineInputBorder(), // UnderlineInputBorder(),
                  hintText: 'Paste class link here',
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Center(
                child: Text(
              "Timing",
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: ht / 30, fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),
            )),
            Row(mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center, children: [
              // BasicTimeField(),
              SizedBox(
                width: wd / 9,
                child: Center(
                  child: Text(
                    "to",
                    style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: ht / 40, fontWeight: FontWeight.w400),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              // BasicTimeField()
            ]),
            SizedBox(
              height: ht / 40,
            ),
            Center(
                child: Text(
              "Select days of week",
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: ht / 30, fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),
            )),
            // DayPicker(),
            SizedBox(
              height: ht / 20,
            ),
            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                ElevatedButton(
                  child: Text('Add'),
                  onPressed: () => formKey.currentState?.save(),
                ),
                const SizedBox(
                  width: 50,
                ),
                ElevatedButton(
                  child: Text('Reset'),
                  onPressed: () => formKey.currentState?.reset(),
                ),
              ],
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**Output**

*Entering data*

[image]

*Clearing after reset is pressed*

[image]

Answer (score 2):

```
formKey.currentState?.reset()
```

This line of code resets all the **form fields** that are descendant of Form(). It only works on TextFormField widgets.

You can change all *TextField* widgets to *TextFormField*, so the reset would work on them.